# How to prevent storing nil value in rails cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I am using redis-store for caching in my application,I don't want to fetch the key and value if the value returns nil.

```
Rails.cache.fetch{"user_by_comment_id:#{params['comment_id']}"} do
 User.find_by_comment_id(params['comment_id'])
end
```

if it return the nil for the key "user_by_comment_id:#{params['comment_id']}",I don't want to store the key in my cache.Help me to solve this.

Comment: If it returns nil it wont write anything in the cache

Comment: it writes nil for the key.I don't want to write cache key if it returns nil.

Comment: What about using a method that throws exception if no record is found (that's dirty as hell but I see no other way around it)

Comment: Also - if there's no user found by comment id it means comment does not belogs to anyone. Isn't there a problem with data consistency?

Comment: `User.find_by_comment_id!(params['comment_id'])`

Answer (score 15):

Update:

From rails 6.0.0, you can supply the `skip_nil: true` option while calling `Rails.cache.fetch`

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L719.)

Thanks [Rick Suggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940754/rick-suggs) for pointing this out.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can compare the rails 5.2.1 source to the pull request, and see that `skip_nil` is not supported in 5.2.1. It is not until 6.0.0 that the option is supported. Please update. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L697 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L719

Answer (score 4):

You can add methods in the Rails.cache class to handle your case (put that code in initializer somewhere):

```
   module ActiveSupport
   module Cache
    class Store
      def fetch_no_nil(name, options = nil)
        if block_given?
          options = merged_options(options)
          key = namespaced_key(name, options)

          cached_entry = find_cached_entry(key, name, options) unless options[:force]
          entry = handle_expired_entry(cached_entry, key, options)

          if entry
            get_entry_value(entry, name, options)
          else
            save_block_result_to_cache_if_not_nil(name, options) { |_name| yield _name }
          end
        else
          read(name, options)
        end
      end
      private
      def save_block_result_to_cache_if_not_nil(name, options)
        result = instrument(:generate, name, options) do |payload|
          yield(name)
        end
        write(name, result, options) unless result.nil?
        result
      end
    end
  end
  end
```

And then use :

```
Rails.cache.fetch_no_nil{"user_by_comment_id:#{params['comment_id']}"} do
 User.find_by_comment_id(params['comment_id'])
end
```

Comment: @Achaius If you find the answer useful then upvote it and if the answer is correct please accept it This will help to remove your question from the list of unanswered question. This doesn't mean accept my answer you may accept the answer which is useful to you. Thanks